# How do I redo multiple times in emacs with a shortcut like ctrl+_

Tags: emacs, undo-redo

I like how I can undo multiple times with ctrl+_, but I can't seem to figure out how to redo that supports multiple times with a similar quick shortcut.

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to skip multiple lines up and down at once.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "skip multiple lines up and down at once."

Comment: Skip multiple lines: `C-3 C-p` where `3` is the number of lines you want to skip, and `p` is one of `p` or `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to figure out how to redo that supports multiple times with a similar quick shortcut.

Sorry if you know this...

You can switch undo to redo by hitting `C-g` once. So it is not one shortcut key. The behavior is not like as ordinary editor. But I think it is very quick way of redo. See the behavior below.

Emacs undo state changes:

```
----example1------
time |typed |text
-----+------+-----
1    |      |''
2    |'a'   |'a'
3    |'b'   |'ab'
4    |'c'   |'abc'
5    |'d'   |'abcd'
6    |udno  |'abc'
7    |undo  |'ab'
8    |undo  |'a'
9    |undo  |''
10   |C-g   |''     <---switch
11   |undo  |'a'    <---redo!
12   |undo  |'ab'   <---redo!
13   |undo  |'abc'  <---redo!
14   |undo  |'abcd' <---redo!

----example2------
time |typed |text
-----+------+-----
1    |      |''
2    |'a'   |'a'
3    |'b'   |'ab'
4    |'c'   |'abc'
5    |'d'   |'abcd'
6    |udno  |'abc'
7    |undo  |'ab'
8    |undo  |'a'
9    |undo  |''
10   |C-g   |''    <---switch
11   |undo  |'a'   <---redo!
12   |undo  |'ab'  <---redo!
13   |'x'   |'abx' <---switch
14   |undo  |'ab'
15   |undo  |'a'
16   |C-g   |'a'   <---switch
17   |undo  |'ab'  <---redo!!
18   |undo  |'abx' <---redo!!
```

Answer (score 5):

Vanilla Emacs undo has no associated redo.  You can find various redos out there -- start at [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Search?action=index&match=redo), for example.

However, you might just prefer, as many of us do, what ordinary Emacs undo has to offer.  In a nutshell, it records like a film, which means that if you exit it (stop undoing) and then you start undoing again, you ***undo what you just undid!***  You can go "back and forth" like this, as far as you like.

You don't really go forwards (redo) that way, however: you just keep undoing.  And ***undoing*** *undoing* has a similar effect to redoing.  If you go too far, just quit undoing and start over.  (Hit any other key, e.g. `RET`, to quit undoing.)

See also various wiki pages about [undo](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs?action=index&match=undo&pages=on&manual=1&.submit=Go%21), including [**UndoTree**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree).